# Does Firefox really support the `type` option for the Worker constructor?

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-worker, es6-modules

I can't seem to be able to instantiate a web worker from a ES6 script file. MDN says it should be possible like this:

```
const worker = new Worker('my-worker.js', {type:"module"});
```

That doesn't work for me, I get an error:

```
 SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

### MCVE:

#### `test.html`

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><script type="text/javascript">
    new Worker("worker.js", { type: "module" });

    </script></body>
</html>
```

#### `worker.js`

```
import Nothing from "./nothing.js";
```

Firefox version: 62.0.2

Comment: MDN says that `Worker` works like that, it doesn't say that Firefox has implemented this feature already.

Comment: @Bergi It does not mention the support of the feature at all, either way.

Comment: As of today, this is still an issue, unfortunately. Tested with Firefox 75.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox resolved the support for `type: module` in February 2023:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1247687

According Caniuse, this support was shipped as Firefox v114 in June 2023:

https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_worker_worker_ecmascript_modules

Comment: Yes, I have already used it this year and it worked. I just forgot I actually asked a question about it.

Answer (score 6):

No it currently (April 2021) does not, see this feature request for details:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1247687